# bootstrap carousel tranistioning wrong - no errors shown

Tags: javascript, joomla, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a carousel here:
http://www.joostrap.com/extensions/bootstrap-carousel-module

Rather than sliding to the left, it is sliding up, disappearing, then down again (chrome).

Any ideas?
(I'm not really a JavaScript person)

Comment: Please add an example of the code you are using.  Linking to a Joomla plugin is not sufficient. If your question is just about using an extension in Joomla, it might be better fit for [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joomla).

Comment: @merv: don't really think this belong to Pro Webmasters, however you're right, code needs to be provided. If you are having problems with a specific extension because its not functioning properly, you should contact the developer.